# url query parameter parsing , best option

Tags: php

I have in my url this

```
http://www.test.com/?jjjanu@gmail.com&amp;tid=RetEm_Welcome_resp_05232012
```

issue isn that it is not

```
http://www.test.com/?email = jjjanu@gmail.com&amp;tid=RetEm_Welcome_resp_05232012

notice email = jjjanu@gmail.com
```

so I can't do `$_GET['email']`
how can I get the email address from the above string?

Comment: If you have no control over those incoming calls, but if you know email will always be the first part, you may want to consider using mod-rewrite to capture that email address and give it a proper name for internal use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples given will not work with the desired `$_GET['email']`.

The first example, `http://www.test.com/?jjjanu@gmail.com&tid=RetEm_Welcome_resp_05232012`, has no "key" for the email address, so the only way to get it would be to iterate through each query-string parameter and either assume that a no-key value is an email address or do a regex-match on it. Something (very) basic would be:

```
$email = '';
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
    if (strpos($key, '@') && ($val == '')) {
        // assume this is an email address
        $email = $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

The second example, `http://www.test.com/?email = jjjanu@gmail.com&tid=RetEm_Welcome_resp_05232012`, the space after the word "email" counts in the name. It could be retrieved with:
`$email = $_GET['email '];`

Is there a specific reason why a regular `?email=[email address]` query-string won't work?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer to this is `foreach` over `$_GET` and look for an email address in the keys. **However** this will not work, because PHP will transform the `.` in the email address (and potentially other characters as well) into `_` characters for backwards compatibility with `register_globals`. This makes the task a little more difficult, <strike>but not impossible:</strike>

Just been playing with it, and actually it *is* impossible, because PHP actually consumes the `.` in the email address and converts it to a `_` even when you get the raw query string from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Sorry.

It probably would work with a POST request because I don't think PHP will modify the data that can be obtained from `php://input` - but if you could modify this, you could presumably modify the request URL so that it had a proper key and none of this would be a problem.

Comment: there is no `=` so this line `explode('=', $val, 2);` fails

Comment: No it doesn't, it will just return the first part and populate key. The reason it fails (and this is my bad) is because it should be `list($key, $val) = explode('=', $data, 2);`

Comment: *However* it still doesn't work, because PHP is still eating the `.` in the email address, even when you get the raw query from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. So the short answer is - it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could get string of request uri by

```
$query=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

After that you may parse this query as you wish